# Rational equations word problem

Tags: integers

A French club collected the same amount from each student going on a trip. When six students could not go, each of the remaining students was charged 3 dollars extra. If the total cost was $540, how many students went on the trip?

So far I've got Let x=The amount of students.
x-6

Comment: The idea is probably that the group of French students travelled for a fixed total cost. So initially (N + 6) students would travel, at a cost C per person. But actually N travelled at a cost of (C + 3) per person. Given that the total cost is $540, you can determine N and C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the cost of the trip is constant, you can make two equations based on $x$, the total number of students in the class, and $y$, the cost per student when all the students were going on the trip.

From this it is easy to see that $xy=540$, because $x$ students would each pay $y$ dollars to go on the trip.

Given 6 less students, each paying 3 dollars less, the equation becomes $(x-6)(y-3) = 540$, because the cost of the trip remains the same.

Hopefully you can see that this is a nice system of equations for you to solve.